# Run "docker build" command in a Gitlab Pipeline

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a Gitlab Pipeline where I do some tests and then build a Docker image. See the snippet of what it looks like:

```
image:
  name: node:18.13.0-alpine
  entrypoint: [""]

stages:
  - test
  - build

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - yarn install
    - yarn test:coverage

publish:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build -t someimage:123 .
```

I have two questions with this:

1. How do I pass the **node_modules** folder from the **test** to the **build** stage?
2. The **node:18.13.0-alpine** image doesn't have Docker installed on it. How do I go about it?

Comment: 1. With [artefacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_artifacts.html#view-all-job-artifacts-in-a-project), they are shared from stages to stages. 2. Build your own image or install it with a `- apk add --no-cache docker-cli` step under `script`.

Comment: General SO rule, though: refrain from asking multiple questions in one, this would tend make your question highly localised to your context and less likely to be helpful for someone else in the future.

Comment: Thanks for that. I will give it a go. Do you want to put that as an answer so when I test it, I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Using [Gitlab Artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_artifacts.html).
2. There are many ways to achieve this. One of them is to use the [official Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker) and install NodeJs over it. Also, you need [Docker In Docker](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html) to build an image. The thing is, Docker is a client-server app, so you can't build just using a single Docker image. The client (docker:24.0.7) will be in your main job's [image](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#image) and the server (docker:24.0.7-dind) in the job's [service](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#services).